# SQL insert into select return values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

Help to understand how to return values from stored procedure , this is a multi values,

Need to return Id and Status of new inserted row

this piece of table

```
create table mytable
(
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
name NVARCHAR(255),
tran_status NVARCHAR(255)
);
```

this piece of stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateByXml
(
@XML ntext
)
AS

DECLARE @idoc INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT,  @XML

BEGIN

DECLARE @t TABLE(
            [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            [tran_status] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        )

INSERT @t 
    SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '//item', 1) 
        WITH (
            [Name] NVARCHAR(255) '@Name'
            , [tran_status] NVARCHAR(255) '@tran_status'
        ) a

        INSERT INTO mytable ([id], [name], [tran_status])
        SELECT 
            NEWID()
            ,t.Name
            ,t.tran_status
        FROM @t t
END
```

Stored procedure is working just need to add functionality for returning inserting statement, but only if that completely inserted, because in a future not all values will inserted from temp table

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: IF you're passing in XML - why don't you use the `XML` datatype for the parameter?? That would make a lot more sense.....

Comment: You know I've just ask some another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#CaptureResults) clause in your insert.

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
([id], [name], [tran_status])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[id],
INSERTED.tran_status
SELECT...
```

Comment: A lot of thanks. I'm really forgot about this. Just one question how to use this output in another statement in NEXT STEP